# How do I return the variable from a function?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to return a variable from a function and print it out. Its displaying unexpected T_STRING right now.... Can someone help?

```
function reg_word($i){
        $reg_word = "/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/";
        $i = preg_replace($reg_word, '', $i);
    }

$suggestion = function reg_word($_POST['suggestions']);

    print_r($suggestion);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function reg_word($i){
    $reg_word = "/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/";
    return preg_replace($reg_word, '', $i);
}

$suggestion = reg_word($_POST['suggestions']);

print_r($suggestion);
```

You had `function` keyword before `reg_word($_POST['suggestions']);` - you don't need it.
You need to use `return` keyword to return something from a function.

Answer (score 0):

You've got one `function` keyword wrong, try:

```
function reg_word($i){
        $reg_word = "/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/";
        $i = preg_replace($reg_word, '', $i);
    }

$suggestion = reg_word($_POST['suggestions']);

    print_r($suggestion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong `function` keyword, you do NOT return any value in function.

```
function reg_word($i){
        $reg_word = "/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/";
        return preg_replace($reg_word, '', $i); // return added
    }

$suggestion = reg_word($_POST['suggestions']); // here function was

    print_r($suggestion);
```